# CoordinateTransformData (cartesian to spherical)

Tags: bugs, version-9, coordinate-transformation

I am using *Mathematica* v9.0.1.0 and wanted to compare *Mathematica's* `CoordinateTransformData` command to Matlab's `cart2sph`. (Note that `cart2sph` is defined **completely** differently, and I need it in the other form, hence why I would like to check).

I will demonstrate my problem in the form of an example. In particular, for three randomly chosen coordinate points in cartesian (x, y, z) coordinates, I would like to have their spherical (r, theta, phi) coordinate representation.

I will paste the code in below:

```
CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", "Mapping", {1, 2.0, 3}]
```

> ```
> {3.74166, 0.640522, 1.10715}
> ```

```
CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", "Mapping", {.4, 0.2, -1}]
```

> ```
> {1.09545, 2.72106, 0.463648}
> ```

Both of the above are correct, but

```
CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", "Mapping", {-0.6, 1.8, -4}]
```

prints the error message:

> CoordinateTransformData::bdpt: Evaluation point {-0.6, 1.8, -4} is incompatible with the coordinate assumptions of the specified coordinate chart. >>

If I simply follow the definitions given on Wikipedia and write my own script:

```
comparcart2sphr[x_, y_, z_] := 
  {Sqrt[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2], ArcCos[z/Sqrt[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}
```

then

```
comparcart2sphr[1, 2.0, 3]
```

> ```
> {3.74166, 0.640522, 1.10715}
> ```

```
comparcart2sphr[.4, .2, -1]
```

> ```
>  {1.09545, 2.72106, 0.463648}
> ```

```
comparcart2sphr[-.6, 1.8, -4]
```

> ```
> {4.42719, 2.69868, 1.89255}
> ```

Can someone explain why *Mathematica* cannot handle this? I realise that this is because of the assumption they have in their chart, but surely it should be able to handle all points in R3. From the help file of `CoordinateTransformData` one could also write

```
mathematicahelpexpr[x_, y_, z_] := 
  {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}
```

and obtain

```
mathematicahelpexpr[-.6, 1.8, -4]
```

> ```
> {4.42719, 2.69868, 1.89255}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in V9. In V10,

```
 CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", "Mapping", {-0.6, 1.8, -4}]
```

returns

> ```
> {4.42719, 2.69868, 1.89255}
> ```

as expected.